# Here REST API - Max speed of a road

Tags: api, rest, here-api

I would like to get the current max speed authorized of the road on which I'm located.
The `/revgeocode` endpoint of the Geocoding and Search API gives me a lot of information on the road located by coords provided but I have no maxSpeed data.

```
curl -X 'GET' \
'https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=<my_location>&limit=1&apiKey=<my_key>' \
\-H 'accept: application/json'
```

Is there a mean to retrieve the maxSpeed authorized on a road from coords?

I tried to use the the Routing API (`/route` endpoint) but the usage is overkill for my simple need.